# Get map image from MKMapView

Tags: iphone

I have place a mapview as hidden in my application. The map image need to be obtained from the mapview and send as email. How can i get the map image from the hidden mapview.

Thanks,

Comment: For anyone coming across this there's now a class called MKMapSnapshotter that may be helpful

Answer (score 12):

For SDK:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mapView.bounds.size);
[self.mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

For toolchain (using Private API)

```
CGRect rect = [self.mapView bounds];
// Change the snapshot rect if needed. 
CGImageRef image = [self.mapView createSnapshotWithRect:rect];
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work for iPhone 4s....all other devices are fine, simulator included...thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup pixel context using `CGBitmapContextCreate`
2. Render `MKMapView` using `[mapView.layer renderInContext:myContext]`
3. Get `CGImage` from context using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`
4. Wrap `CGImage` into `UIImage` if needed.