# iPhone MKMapView in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

Each cell of my UITableView has to display a small MKMapView with an annotation inside.
I managed to do this by creating my custom Cell and configuring its MKMapView in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. The locations are based on an array I build earlier.

Everything works fine but the MKMapViews refresh everytime I scroll the UITableView.
Is ther a way to "cache" the MKMapViews ?

Thanks

Comment: are you alloc'ing a new map view in cellForRowAtIndexPath or are they stored in an array?

Comment: No they are not stored in an array because I didn't manage to do that. I tried to create an array of MapViews in the viewDidLoad (the array was ok) and to get the correct mapView based on the indexPath.row in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but the mapviews were all the same in the tableView... Any idea?

Comment: Very strange. I don't know what the problem is. All I can tell you is that scroll views behave strangely when you nest them. So a map view, which uses something similar to a scroll view, might just not work right inside a table view. You could try @Richard Venable's suggestion and draw the map to an image if your just trying to show a single location in each map view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be configuring the map views in cellForRowAtIndexPath, instead configure them and store them in an array in viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib. Then just set the cell's map view in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Thanks Rich that's what I did in cellForRowAtIndexPath : if the object of the mapViewsDictionnary at index (indexPath.row) is nil, then configure the mapView and add it to the mapViewsDictionnary; else, don't do anything. It works but I don't know if it's really nice and optimized...

Comment: lazy loading can be slow, but the only alternative is to do it in viewDidLoad. One possible optimization would be to copy a single map view, like a prototype. Then initialize it with your data.

Answer (score 8):

You could cache a UIImage of your MKMapView using the method described here: [Get map image from MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553573/get-map-image-from-mkmapview)

You should use that UIImage as often as possible, and only display the actual map when the user needs to interact with it. For best performance, you could try always using the UIImage in the tableview and when the user taps on the row, load the real map (perhaps in its own view controller).

Comment: Is this really possible to create a UIImage of a UIview without displaying this UIView ? I tried the solution you mentioned but I get an empty image, event if I wait for the Map to finish loading. I wonder if it's due to the fact that I don't display the MKMapViews before creating an image of them...

Comment: I haven't made a UIImage of a map myself, I just saw that post and thought it might be helpful. There is more discussion on the same issue in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159596/make-a-uiimage-from-a-mkmapview

Comment: Also, you should check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591835/thumbnail-image-in-info-view-of-maps-app-is-uiimageview-or-mkmapview-or-something

It brings up another unfortunate issue - that you still need to display the Google logo, which might be inconvenient in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a uitableview cell global object in the header file with @property and assign the cell to the global object, if the cell is nil.

Then each time you enters the cellforrowatindexpath check whether the object is nil or not.. If not nil , return the global object .

//in class.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *mapCell;
```

//in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (mapCell == nil) {
                        allocate the cell
                    }
                    else{
                        return mapCell;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, use `MKMapSnapshotter` to create images from the map (in the background thead - no lag!), add the pins manually and then you can cache the images and make it blazing fast. I've provided some code here - http://synappse.co/mkmapview-too-slow-use-preview/