# Load MKMapView in UITableViewCell quickly

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, mkmapview

I'm only a relatively new iPhone programmer so hopefully this makes sense.

I've created a `UITableView` in a `storyboard` and it is displaying correctly. I have created two different types of prototype table view cells. One is just a simple cell displaying text using the "Left Detail" style while the other contains an `MKMapView` and a toolbar. I create a single instance of the map an all the rest of the cells are the simple text cells.

The problem I am having is that when the table view is initially displayed, the `UITableViewCell` containing the map is off-screen. When I scroll down, the UI pauses while the cell is loaded. Based on Instruments, it seems that the time is spent in `[MKMapView initWithCoder]` but I don't know of any way to load the prototype cell before dequeuing it.

Previously the map cell was above-the-fold so was loaded before I did any scrolling. Now that I have rearranged things, it is loading later and causing a delay.

Is there any way that I can pre-load the `UITableViewCell` containing the `MKMapView`, or put some of the loading of the `MKMapView` into the background?

Comment: Is the map user-iteractive ? Is your target >= 7.0, or do you support 6 as well ?

Comment: The map is user-interactive. Also, it's really just a personal project at the moment so currently the target is >=7.0 although that may change  if I see a need.

Comment: Also, I did notice that when I run the app standalone on the device, the performance is almost acceptable. The slowdown is much more noticeable when I running it with the Xcode debugger.

Comment: This happens a lot when using `XIB`s/`storyboard`s. You might want to do it programmatically (create, add, and modify) your map. The performance improvement will not be *great* but it does make a difference. Also, one thing you might want to do is, try using `MKMapSnapshotter` to add a placeholder snapshot in the cell, while the map is actually loading, and remove the snapshot as soon as it finishes loading.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Interesting about using `MKMapSnapshotter` while the map is loading. I'd read about using it to create a picture but hadn't considered using it while loading. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preload the `MKMapView` view instance before, add it as subview to the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That way the map view have some time to load before the cell is displayed.

Comment: Does that mean that I should remove the MKMapView from the prototype cell and just add it in when I display it in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Also, if I create the map, it won't display until I actually call addSubview? I made a little progress down that path yesterday but haven't quite finished my changes.

Comment: @Mike Yes exactly.. I'm guessing you have only one map view to display and this method would be suitable for that. Im not sure about the map view not loading until it is added as subview. If that is the case, then you temporarily add it as subview to some view with a tiny frame size which wouldnt be visible. Later you can switch it onto an ur cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems a bit quicker now. Has taken me a while to get the code sorted out so sorry for the slow response.

Answer (score 1):

Other way of doing it would be using `MKMapSnapshotter`, do a background fetch and cache the result. Please check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479479/384288, maybe it will help someone.